# Symfony login form validation

Tags: authentication, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

How I can validate login form BEFORE login_check? It's important to tell user, that email is invalid, rather then "bad credentials".

Should i use event listeners? Or simple redirect to login_check in controller action after form validate?

PS. I cannot find any solution or advice for symfony2.1

Comment: FOSUserBundle is supposed to output 'Invalid username or password' as defined in language file FOSUserBundle.en.yml. Seems good enough to me.

Comment: Ok, but I want to return "Invalid e-mail format" instead of "invalid username or password".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Symfony2 [email field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/email.html):

```
$builder->add('email', 'email', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Email'),
    'label' => '* Email: '
));
```

Comment: I don't need to override translation messages, I need to validate login form. FOSUserBundle (and Symfony auth) didn't validate form, it just try to find user. So error just "Incorrect login (email) or password". I need validate "email" field against email format. So there are two types on error "Incorrect login" or "Incorrect email format".

Comment: OK, I think I understood your question now :) Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But again, it isn't provide server-side validation logic.

Comment: Anyway, seems like no one had an answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: This will only work for html5 enabled browsers. Any ideas for server side validation?

Comment: have a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316166/symfony2-how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-a-controller